# Website on high resolution screen is too small

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, zooming

I have a web page with a responsive design (I used Bootstrap). Everything works very well for mobile, tablet, and desktop sizes. But when I am using high resolution screens or devices (more than 1920x1080px) the website becomes very small.

I tried zoom for high resolution devices, but I'm getting bugs (listed below).

```
@media (min-width: 1900px){ 
  html { 
    zoom: 150%;
    -ms-zoom: 1.5;
    -webkit-zoom: 1.5;
    -moz-transform:  scale(1.5,1.5);        
    transform-origin: center top ;
  } 
  body {  /* use only for IE */
    zoom: 1.5;        
    /* -ms-transform-origin: left top; */
  }
}
```

Bugs:

1. Not centered in IE
2. Affects jScrollPane plugin scrolling speed in IE and Firefox

Are there other solutions?

Comment: The thing to check is to look at Bootstrap's site on the same screen. I have a cinema display, very large, and it's the right size, so there's something incorrect with your CSS. Are you thinking that it's too narrow? That can be adjusted by media queries.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to mess with zooms.. Just add the following line to your `head` section.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I already have it                                               `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it was Using [CSS Browser Selector](https://github.com/crucifyer/css-browser-selector/) to manually center and fix the website in IE, apart from that, zoom is a really good alternative when you don't want to re build the website for high resolution screens.